# How to run a Powershell script from SAS?

Tags: powershell, sas

I have a code which opens powershell but does not run the script.  How do I run the script? Any help appreciated.

```
x 'C:\Windows\syswow64\Windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -filename "L:\Work\SAS Data\.local2remote1.ps1" ;
```

Comment: maybe `-file` instead of `-filename` 
`x 'C:\Windows\syswow64\Windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe' -file "L:\Work\SAS Data\.local2remote1.ps1" ;`

Comment: It's still the same. Opens powershell only.

Comment: The trick is to find the code required from command line or RUN window and use that. Appears to be 'X "powershell path_to_ps file"';

Comment: Note that ideally you have no spaces in path but can get around that if you have to.

Comment: Thanks! it worked.

Answer (score 1):

```
x 'powershell -file "L:\Work\SAS Data\local2remote1.ps1"';
```

is the correct syntax